# How android deals with static classes?

Tags: android

I got a class with the following architecture:

```
public class StaticClass{
    private static LruCache<Obj> list = new LruCache<Obj>();

    public static LruCache<Obj> getList(){
           return list;
    }
}
```

Now, references to this list are used just in plain activities.
However, an activity launches a service which will continue to exist even after every activity is closed.
Given that a service exists in a process, do references to static list continue to exist?
I'm asking this because my service takes a lot of memory and I'm sure that memory should be less, moreover when I open the application again I see that everything is much faster (that lru cache is for bitmap caching) , so I'd guess that static continues to exist..

**edit:**
It's really strange! If I nullify static references and then reopen application I get a null pointer exception from my cursor adapter! Indeed, cursor adapter code is like this:

```
public MyAdapter(){
     cache = StaticClass.getCache();
}

public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor c) {
     cache.get(...) //this throws null pointer exception
```

so the only thing I can think of is that adapter is that my main activity is not closed...but it is: onDestroy() is called: I checked it! And my service has no reference at all to the adapter!

Comment: Law of Physics: As long as we are on the same process, we share the same statics.

Comment: I liked your way of explanation. +1

Comment: And yes, static variables don't get removed automatically. Only when your process is killed or you when you explicitly `null` them.

Comment: Then gimme +1 thanks! :D Mmm..so basically in the onDestroy() method of the main activity I just have to nullify these variables? I though using WeakReferences but maybe is less tricky in this way?

Comment: It doesn't work: apparently problem is on my app which is not closed at all but I can't understand why